# Duplicate and modify lines using Sed

Tags: sed

Let's consider a SQL file as input (i.e. myTable.sql) containing the following statement :

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE OR REPLACE PUBLIC SYNONYM ' || myTable || ' FOR SCHEMA1.' || myTable;
```

Is there a simple way (using sed) to duplicate this statement and modify them as follows ?

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE OR REPLACE SYNONYM SCHEMA2.' || myTable || ' FOR SCHEMA1.' || myTable;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE OR REPLACE SYNONYM SCHEMA3.' || myTable || ' FOR SCHEMA1.' || myTable;
```

Thanks a lot for your help.
M.

*** EDIT ***

First part can be solved like this :

```
sed -i -e '/PUBLIC SYNONYM/p' myTable.sql
```

Second part is about two search-and-replace commands :

```
sed -i -e '0,/PUBLIC SYNONYM/s/PUBLIC SYNONYM /SYNONYM SCHEMA2./' myTable.sql
sed -i -e '0,/PUBLIC SYNONYM/s/PUBLIC SYNONYM /SYNONYM SCHEMA3./' myTable.sql
```

I consider my question has been answered.  Feel free to reply if you find something more efficient.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

First part can be solved like this :

```
sed -i -e '/PUBLIC SYNONYM/p' myTable.sql
```

Second part is about two search-and-replace commands :

```
sed -i -e '0,/PUBLIC SYNONYM/s/PUBLIC SYNONYM /SYNONYM SCHEMA2./' myTable.sql
sed -i -e '0,/PUBLIC SYNONYM/s/PUBLIC SYNONYM /SYNONYM SCHEMA3./' myTable.sql
```

I consider my question has been answered. Feel free to reply if you find something more efficient. Cheers.